# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: local date not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I am getting this error when trying to send a request:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8
> date/time type `java.time.LocalDate` not supported by default: add
> Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to
> enable handling

I have added the dependency as well and tried to register it with:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return mapper;
}
```

Though it still giving the same error. I don't want to add notations on the entity properties because they are generated sources from an Open API. Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: IIRC, you need to add `@Primary` to the bean definition. Be aware, there are other options to configure the object mapper used by Spring Boot, see also [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it didn't work

Comment: The link I added to my previous comment suggests defining a bean returning the `JavaTimeModule`.